# QEMU AArch64 Seems to Hang with no Log Messages

Tags: debian, qemu

I am trying to build a Debian 10 on a QEMU Aarch 64 virt architecture.
For this purpose I follow [this guide](https://translatedcode.wordpress.com/2017/07/24/installing-debian-on-qemus-64-bit-arm-virt-board/).

I fetched the two part kernel installer from Debian mirror from:

```
wget -O installer-linux http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/debian-installer/amd64/linux
wget -O installer-initrd.gz http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/debian-installer/amd64/initrd.gz
```

Then, I launched the qemu-system-aarch64 instruction to  build the kernel and run the installer as follows on my Debian Host machine after creating a 16G empty disk hda.qcow2:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -m 2048 -cpu cortex-a53 \
-kernel installer-linux -initrd installer-initrd.gz \
-drive if=none,file=hda.qcow2,format=qcow2,id=hd \
-device virtio-blk-pci,drive=hd -netdev user,id=mynet \
-device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet -nographic \
-no-reboot -append "console=ttyAMA0"
```

However, the instruction does not show any "verbose" messages and "just" runs for hours. I tried it several times but I do not see any installed kernel. What should this do and how long does it run? There are no interactive messages as mentioned in the tutorial. I am behind a proxy. Should I configure something? 
How to check any error log messages? "top" command shows that the qemu-system-aarch64 executable runs with 90% cpu :(

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: `...debian-installer/amd64/linux` ... do you want AMD64 or AArch64 ?